# Async/await call returns undefined when used in conjunction with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I am having an issue where an Async call to my database returns undefined.
The function "findOne" retrieves one row from the database, but the `.then(...` function is executing before the row is returned.

I've tried changing what I return in the DB function `findOne` as well as adding an 'await' on the function call. I've also tried using `Promise.resolve(db.findOne({requestbody}).then(...` but no luck with that either.

Here is the `db.findOne` method

```js
const findOne = async (req) => {
    const { teamId, channelId, isClosed } = req;
    return db.query('SELECT * FROM polls where team_id= $1 and channel_id =$2 and is_closed = $3 LIMIT 1',
        [teamId, channelId, isClosed],
        (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }
            console.log("\nDBRes: \n", results.rows[0])
            return results.rows[0];
        }
    );
};
```

And here is where I call the function

```js
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const slashCommand = req.body.command;
    switch (slashCommand) {
//...
//... Some other code
//...
        case 'results':
            db.findOne({
                teamId: requestBody.team_id,
                 channelId: requestBody.channel_id,
                 isClosed: false,
            })
            .then((row) => {
                 console.log(row);
                 const poll = pollFuncs.getPollfromResultRow(row);
                 const displayText = pollFuncs.getFormattedPollResults(poll);
                 res.status(200).send({
                     text: displayText,
                 });
             });
         break;
//... The rest of the function
```

Here are the logs I am getting.
Note* I am currently logging the "row" object both inside the `.then(...)` function and inside the `pollFuncs.getPollfromResultRow(row);` function

```
Bot is listening on port 3000
undefined
undefined
(node:14000) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot destructure property `id` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
    at Object.getPollfromResultRow (C:\Users\ztb0504\Documents\Projects\Node\werewolfmod\pollFunctions.js:97:125)
    at db.findOne.then (C:\Users\ztb0504\Documents\Projects\Node\werewolfmod\index.js:59:56)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:14000) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14000) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

DBRes:
 { id: '22',
  poll_title: 'This is a new Pollstgresql',
  //The rest of the expected data....
 }
```

I'd appreciate any guidance on how to get this to return data as expected.
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: An unrelated note: You are throwing the error from the db callback stack rather than into your promise. You should not do that.

Comment: @SOFe jfriend00's answer addresses that issue as well. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing plain callbacks and promises and it is causing you problems.  It will be a lot easier if you don't do that.

If you pass a plain callback to `db.query()`, then it won't return a promise.  In fact, it will return nothing (`undefined`).  So, when you do `return db.query()`, all you're doing is returning `undefined`.

Change to this:

```
const findOne = async (req) => {
    const { teamId, channelId, isClosed } = req;
    return db.query('SELECT * FROM polls where team_id= $1 and channel_id =$2 and is_closed = $3 LIMIT 1',
        [teamId, channelId, isClosed]).then(results) => {
            console.log("\nDBRes: \n", results.rows[0])
            return results.rows[0];
    });
};
```

The, you also need error handling in your request handler if there are any errors in the query.  Promise handling should nearly always have a `.catch()` somewhere to handle errors:

```
                case 'results':
                    db.findOne({
                        teamId: requestBody.team_id,
                        channelId: requestBody.channel_id,
                        isClosed: false,
                    }).then((row) => {
                            console.log(row);
                            const poll = pollFuncs.getPollfromResultRow(row);
                            const displayText = pollFuncs.getFormattedPollResults(poll);
                            res.status(200).send({
                                text: displayText,
                            });
                    }).catch(err => {
                            console.log(err);
                            res.sendStatus(500);
                    });
                    break;
```